# How to avoid error "VP Notify mechanism incomplete after" in Informix using Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, informix, glusterfs

I'm running Informix enterprise replication inside Kubernetes from past 3 months and haven't faced any problem earlier. But recently I faced one issue where the Informix server was in the running state but unable fetch any record. Then I killed the container and restarted it, and then issue is resolved but I'm unable to find the root cause.
Please find the error below.

```
05:38:08  listener-thread@soc_be.c:3073: err = -25582: oserr = 0: errstr = from 192-168-23-14.<> to server ids121 : Network connection is broken.

05:48:13  VP Notify mechanism incomplete after 5 minutes. This can be due to slow network file access. Will try 11 more times
05:53:15  VP Notify mechanism incomplete after 5 minutes. This can be due to slow network file access. Will try 10 more times
05:58:17  VP Notify mechanism incomplete after 5 minutes. This can be due to slow network file access. Will try 9 more times
06:03:19  VP Notify mechanism incomplete after 5 minutes. This can be due to slow network file access. Will try 8 more times
```

Note: I'm using Gluster cluster PVC and both Informix containers which are running in the same namespace.
Could anyone help me to resolve this issue?

I'm using OpenShift 3.9 and RHEL 7 is the base image used for Informix. I haven't done any changes in Informix image recently. (Informix version 12.10.FC8ADE)

Comment: You need to provide more details. What versions of apps, OS are you using. Based on tag I assume you are using openshift but what version? Did any changes has been made? Any patches, updates?

Comment: I'm using OpenShift 3.9 and RHEL 7 is the base image used for Informix. I haven't done any changes in Informix image recently. (Informix version 12.10.FC8ADE).